# Error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: javascript, api, module.exports, vanilla

intento mostrar los datos que traigo de una api con un forEach, perome sale este error
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

aqui hago la llamada a la api, pero no estoy seguro de porque no trae los datos.

```javascript
export async function getForecast(code){
    //api key
    var API_KEY='PIAcz5bZ3LStSpLy1GsG10hXdqdQcSD3';

    //call api
    const reQuestUrl='http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/'+code+'?apikey='+API_KEY;

    return await fetch(reQuestUrl)
   
    .then( (response) => { return response.json(); })
    .catch( (response) => { console.log(response); })
   



  // const data=await res.json();

    //const climas=data.DailyForecasts;
    //console.log({data,climas});
}
```

en la funcion getInfo quiero imprimir los datos, estoy utilizando modulos a si que llamo a la funcion getForecast e intento traer los datos y los envio a la funcion getInfo donde quiero imprimir los datos de una api con un forEach.

```javascript
import{getForecast} from './info/services.js'

window.addEventListener('load', () => { init(); })
//init
function init() {
    //location ID
    var key=241912;
    load(key);
}
//enviar ID code
function load(code) {
    getForecast(code)
        .then( (response) => { getInfo(response.results); })
}


 function getInfo(climas){

    let template = document.getElementById('template-forecast').content;
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    climas.forEach(clima => {
        console.log(clima);
       //let clim=(clima.Temperature.Maximum.Value-32)*(5/9);
       //let clim2= Math.trunc(clim);
        //template.querySelector('#image').src = clima.Day.Icon; //image
        template.querySelector("#date").textContent = clima.Date; //track name
        //template.querySelector("#temp").textContent = clim2;
        let clone = document.importNode(template, true); //clone fragment
        fragment.appendChild(clone); //add clone to fragmentsrc
        
    });

    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fragment);
}
```

estoy empezando con modulos y estoy teniendo problemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes al menos 2 errores:

1. La función load debe ser así

```
function load(code) {
    getForecast(code)
        .then( (response) => { getInfo(response); })
}
```

Es decir es `response` NO `response.results`

2. Lo que te devuelve es un objeto, no una lista. Por lo que no puede itear con el foreach. La lista viene en la propiedad `DailyForecasts`

```
 function getInfo(climas){

    let template = document.getElementById('template-forecast').content;
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    climas.DailyForecasts.forEach(clima => {
        console.log(clima);
       //let clim=(clima.Temperature.Maximum.Value-32)*(5/9);
       //let clim2= Math.trunc(clim);
        //template.querySelector('#image').src = clima.Day.Icon; //image
        template.querySelector("#date").textContent = clima.Date; //track name
        //template.querySelector("#temp").textContent = clim2;
        let clone = document.importNode(template, true); //clone fragment
        fragment.appendChild(clone); //add clone to fragmentsrc
        
    });

    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Comment: gracias! ya solucione el error!